# Align a button to the bottom right of screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a submit button here on the right of "Action" Button:

[image: Submit Button]

I've tried to use the code:

```
android:gravity="bottom|right"
```

but it doesn't work, and it still stays on the same place.

My full code is this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="@string/select_action"
    android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnSelectPhoto"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

Even with the code above, the layout is still the same as the image. How can I fix this?

Fixed: Added android:layout_alignParentRight="true", Thanks to Egor N.

Answer (score 2):

`android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` should do the job. But, you should get rid of `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnSelectPhoto"`.

`android:gravity` didn't work, because this value is applied to content inside the view (text inside a button).

Comment: Looks like it worked, I did the same thing to the "Action" Button but:


'android:layout_alignParentRight="true"'


instead. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simlpe View between the two bottons

for example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:layout_gravity="end|bottom" to place your component on the right bottom corner of its parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_mapFloatingButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">
 
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mapicon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/gf_map_selected"></ImageButton>
   
</LinearLayout>
```

The android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" and android:layout_alignParentTop="true" do not work for me.